# oracle query sequential summation per rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask to make a query like the following table?

```
-------------------------------------
ID   Date        Input  Output  Total
-------------------------------------
1   2016-05-01  10       0      10
1   2016-05-02  2       -1      11
1   2016-05-03  0       -5      6
1   2016-05-04  0       -1      5
```

assume I have a table "table_a" that has a column (ID, name, date, input, output). how to create query with results as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM OVER` function:

```
SELECT *,
    SUM(Input + Output) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) AS Total
FROM table_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM() OVER(..)` window function which produce cumulative sum :

```
SELECT t.id,t.date,t.input,t.output,
       SUM(t.output+t.input) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.date) as Total
FROM YourTable t
```